# Cryptomatte issue when saving EXR files from output file node Cyptommate passes getting glitched

Tags: render-passes, .exr, output, cryptomatte

i'm working on a professionnal animations right knoww and i'm having a big issue with the crytomate output.
Context :

I will render an animation and i want to have the cryptomatte passes. I'm working on EXR multilayers 32 bit to get all the data and then work on Resolve for correction.
Here is the output node i get to set it right.

[image]

Here the problem :

When the render is saved by the output node even for a simple node set and with simple matérial here the result of the cryptomate passes. I just import the exr in a cryptomatte node using images. This is the result i get in other software too.

[image]

I found that if i saved the render manually by using :
Image>saves as> ....
I get a better result.

[image]

But i cant saved the 2250frames i haves to saves manually.
And i dont understand what is the difference between saving with output node and manually save.
I hope somme of you have the answer. Cause i dont know what to do and i'm quitte in a hurry.
Thanks all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally get the answer. It's a bug. I dont know how i can send this to the dev of blender for maybe a bug fix.
The problem looklike comming from the startupfile i made with the output node.
To solve the problem i have to uncheck all the passe i made. Then recreate the node and after this manipulations it's working again without the glitched edge on the crypto.
If someone need more explaination or if a dev come to this topic I can recreate the bug and solve it.
Hope that will help someone.
Good day !

Comment: To report a bug, click on *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender.